# How to display recent comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

How can I display recent facebook comments, I have three tabs on my website: www.worldinsport.com

Tabs are Headline - Popular - Comments

First two works fine, but comments doesn't as its setup to use default comments system rather than the facebook comments that I use.

Here is the code that would need replacing:

```
<p> <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'com_num' ); ?>">Number of recent comments:</label>
<input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'com_num' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'com_num' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['com_num']; ?>" style="width:20%;" /></p>
```

How can I change this to display recent facebook comments?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you think about using the FB comments box? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ Or maybe you wanted to query the FB API to get the comments and display them in a style more suited to your site?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I currently use Facebook's official wordpress plugin and I'm using their facebook comments system. I want to get the comments to display in the side widget. them comments widget it already there, excpet it's blank where it's programmed to show default comments system and not the facebook one.

Comment: Well if you delete that bit of code and paste in the code for the FB comments box (on the link I pasted before) does it give you what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what the code this to display comments, I have it installed with the offical Facebook plugin

Comment: I'm not sure what the code this to display comments, I have it installed with the offical Facebook plugin

I've just tried: <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div> and it didn't work :-(

Comment: Did you add the FB JS SDK to the page too - when you click to get the code for the FB comments box it has a section which has this too. I don't know if the wordpress plugin will include this on the page by default.

Comment: I have the FB JS SDK in the header

Comment: Anyone got a solution?